# Connect to Mysql with TSQLConnection and SSL

Tags: mysql, delphi, ssl, c++builder, dbexpress

I connect to a MySQL database with a TSQLConnection, where I add the needed connection parameters at runtime with SQLConnectionMySQL->Params-Add("..."). This works as it should.

Now I want to connect to the database with SSL. As I understand I need to add the SSL certificate files in the parameter list somehow. But I can not find out how.

Does anyone have an idea how to do this?

(I use C++Builder XE for this project, but I've also got XE6 installed.)

Regards Tomas

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The DbExpress MySQL drivers included with Delphi [doesn't supports SSL](http://qc.embarcadero.com/wc/qcmain.aspx?d=111064), So you must use a third-party driver like the [DBX for MySQL](https://www.microolap.com/products/connectivity/dbx4mysql/) or use [FIREDAC](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE5/en/Connect_to_MySQL_Server_%28FireDAC%29).